# go get -> cannot download, /home/azhukov/go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH

Tags: go

Good day! I am trying to install gb (vendoring tool for go) in Google Cloud.
I try `go get` and it fails:

```
azhukov@gce-machine:~$ go get -v github.com/constabulary/gb/...
package github.com/pkg/errors: cannot download, /home/azhukov/go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH. For more details see: 'go help gopath'
```

here is env:

```
azhukov@gce-machine:~$ echo $GOPATH, $GOROOT, $PATH
/home/azhukov/go, , /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/azhukov/go/bin
```

go version:

```
azhukov@gce-machine:~$ go version
go version go1.8 linux/amd64
```

go env:

```
azhukov@gce-machine:~$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/azhukov/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build477416510=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

To me everything looks fine, I don't get why would go get return such error. It is counter-logical.

Comment: Seems like your `GOPATH` should be your `GOROOT` and vice versa.

Comment: what is the output of `go env`?

Comment: updated my post

Comment: try this: `export GOPATH="/home/azhukov/go"`

`export GOROOT="/usr/local/go"`

`go get -v github.com/constabulary/gb/...`

Comment: I think GOROOT not required

Comment: didn't work, the same error message :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error is caused by the `go` tool detecting a Go installation in your GOPATH. It's not telling you that your GOPATH is *the* GOROOT (that's a different message), it's telling your GOPATH looks like *a* GOROOT.

Cleaning out your GOPATH and running `go get` again will fix the error.

Comment: Thank you! Cleaning my GOPATH fixed the problem! I have no idea, how go might be installed in my home directory

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning GOPATH?

Comment: I did `rm -rf $GOPATH` and that did the trick. make sure you don't have anything important in there though

Comment: he means removing from env variable: `unset GOPATH`

Comment: What does "Cleaning out your GOPATH" mean?

Answer (score -2):

For mac,

1. run `export GOPATH=$HOME/go` in terminal
2. then run the `go get -u [url]`